# Mountain Lion - Umlauts with english keyboard layout

Tags: macos, keyboard

i have small problems with my keyboard typing umlauts.
On Lion i could type umlauts with " followed by the vowel
This is no longer possible. The only possibility i noticed is to type 
umlauts now by alt+u followed by vowel.

Can i revert this to " + vowel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you using the U.S. International - PC keyboard layout? ⇧' enters a dead key state for inserting umlauts in it.

Comment: Thats it. i tried US instead of US international. thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few means of typing diacritical marks.

### Input Sources Method

You can enable a German Language layout by opening **Language & Text** in System Preferences, going to the *Input Sources*, and checking the box next to German. This isn't quite the same as your previous set up, but it allows you to quickly type ü, ö and ä with the <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd> keys respectively. If you check the *Show Input menu in menu bar* box, you can quickly switch between different layouts, if you want the standard English layout most of the time. The menu also lets you open the Keyboard Viewer, which will show you all the changes of the German layout.

### Create a Custom Keyboard Layout

If the German Layout isn't exactly to your taste, you can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to create a custom layout.

Open Ukelele, and click **File → New From Current Input Source** to start a new layout based on your current one. To make the <kbd>'</kbd> key be your umlaut key (so that you press it, followed by a vowel to create the character), click the **Create** button, click the <kbd>'</kbd> key (or whichever key you want; you can add modifier keys if you wish), then in the dialog that pops up, select **Choose an existing dead key state** and select **State 4**. If you want to rebind another key so that you can still type the `'` character, double click the key you want to change, and change the output to `'`.

You'll then want to change the name of your layout so you can distinguish it. **Set Keyboard Name…** under the **Keyboard** menu will do this for you. You can also set a custom icon if you want.

Once you've finished with your layout, save it to your the `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` folder (or the `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/` folder if you want it to apply for every user on your system). You should then be able to select it in the **Input Sources** section, as above.

### Other Methods

By default on Lion and Mountain Lion, you can hold down a vowel to get a pop-up menu that gives you the various diacritics you can apply to that letter, like so:
[image: diacritic pop-up]

You can either click on the one you want, or type the corresponding letter. This functionality is enabled by default, but can be disabled by running `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` in Terminal. To enable it, replace `false` with `true`.

The other common method, as you have discovered, is to type <kbd>option ⌥</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>, followed by the vowel you want. This works on OS X going back to at least 10.4, possibly earlier.

Comment: Well, yes, but this considerably slows down the writing flow for German users with English keyboard layouts due to the waiting time for each letter.

Comment: I added a new method to my answer, it may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it gives you a single key method of typing umlauts.