# Producing a standard tilde while using OS X (U.S. International - PC) keyboard layout

Tags: macos, keyboard

The tilde, <kbd>~</kbd>, generated by the *U.S. International - PC* layout and the tilde, <kbd>~</kbd>, produced by the *U.S.* layout are allegedly different characters.

How can I produce the *U.S.* tilde while using the International keyboard?

Comment: Both symbols in your question are U+007E TILDE; they’re identical.

Comment: @MathiasBynens While the question currently displays the same tilde character, I think it is clear what the poster intends:  When you don't type a space after it, the US International PC tilde key generates ˜, U+02DC.

Answer (score 5):

To produce the standard tilde (U+007E) with US International PC you just type tilde and then space.  It will be exactly the same as what you get by typing tilde with the US layout.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and then <kbd>space</kbd> for the standard tilde.

Comment: This is the correct answer. And it has the least points.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) if you want to permanently remap, it's got a tonne of options.

Another way to do this, if you're using Lion or above is adding to the `PressAndHold` IOS-esque feature.

[Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) can allegedly do this, or take a look over here: [Mountain Lion - Umlauts with english keyboard layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66450/mountain-lion-umlauts-with-english-keyboard-layout/66452#66452)

Comment: Did you actually try PressAndHold?  As far as I can see it does NOT help you produce a tilde with the US International PC layout.  Also it seems kind of crazy to remap the keyboard for this, when you can just type a space

Comment: I was referring to adding to `PressAndHold` as per the linked answers, tilde isn't in the defaults. I have clarified the wording above. You're right it does seem like overkill to remap the Keyboard or parts of if it but in my experience and workflow it's a one-time maintenance free effective solution. I'm answering with the ways I know how to do this and it's up to the reader how they want to solve it using the options available.