# Add keyboard shortcut to print custom characters

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

I would like to map the Alt (Option) + (a/u/o/s) to ä,ü,ö,ß

Is there a native way, or a software for it?

Comment: Alt/s is already ß. The others are only one more keypress away - alt/u then a, e, i, o, u

Comment: I know, but a direct replacement would be more productive for me

Comment: What is your current keyboard layout? British? German? etc.

Comment: Us International / but I want regular american ABC

Comment: US International PC already has just " plus the base letter to get umlauts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) which is a keyboard layout creator for mac.

I'd recommend "File > New from current input source..."

[image]

Then you can just hold down the ⌥ key and then double-click a key to change its output. Here you can paste your special characters.

[image]

Save your new layout and move it to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`

Then you should be able to choose it from your keyboard/input sources preferences

Comment: that looks like what I want, im gonna give it a try

Comment: Good luck, ask if you need anymore help (I use this so often, it's one of my favourite tools)

Comment: wasn't that easy, since there were problems with saving it but now it works: äöüÄÖÜ :)

Answer (score 1):

There's the default long press functionality, where you long press a letter (~2sec) and it gives you a tooltip with alternatives that are... I guess similar to that letter. You can then press the associated numbers to replace the original letter.

---

You can also navigate the list with:

- `TAB` and `Shift + TAB`
  and
- `←` and `→`
- Pressing `Enter` will replace the original letter.
- Pressing `Esc` will cancel

---

**Example where I long pressed `s`**

[image]

---

**Example where I long pressed `o`:**

I think it doesn't give me the `ö`, because that already exists in my keyboard layout as its own key.

[image]

---

You can adjust the delay for when the tooltip shows up here:

`System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard (first tab) > Delay Until Repeat`

When `Delay Until Repeat` is set to `Short`, the delay is maybe half a second, if I had to guess.

[image]

Comment: Why do your screenshots have this grey border?

Comment: @theonlygusti https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNfDj.jpg

Comment: @theonlygusti In all seriousness, I edited the screenshots to have grey outline, because a screenshot with a white background looks pretty weird in a website with also a white background, especially when the text is cropped out the way it is. [Here's the post from before I edited the images to have the outlines.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/300679/1)

Comment: thanks, i like that, but it would slow me down a bit too much

Comment: @Joonas do you know if there's a way to change the delay for this?

Comment: @theonlygusti I know you can disable it by editing a plist, because that is a question I've seen a lot, where people want to spam letters for what ever reason and this feature prevents that.... but I don't know if you can change the delay.

Comment: @theonlygusti I took a look at that and apparently you can adjust the delay. Updated the bottom of the answer ↑

Comment: I by the way noticed you can kind of use that almost the same way as you would a shortcut. It felt a bit slower long pressing, lifting up my finger and then pressing a number, but I realized that I can actually just keep holding down the key, when I press a number to select the letter.

Comment: @theonlygusti and Strernd, I was thinking about this before.. I decided not to say anything, but might as well now.... you could use the native text replacement thing (maybe.. maybe not) or a third party one (I would recommend [aText](https://www.trankynam.com/atext/) I used it to test this ) to set a key combination to one of these...

Comment: ...special letters. For example, I tested if I it would make sense to convert `.s` to `ß` and that actually felt pretty painless. Period was the best "prefix" character I could think of, that would be quick to write and probably wouldn't create additional problems. So you could also set like `.a` to convert to `ä` and for capitals (for me personally, `shift+.` = `:` ), so `:A` → `Ä`. Also in aText, you can limit the text replacements to specific applications if you want.

Comment: Since I'm pouring out all my ideas, I guess I'm also mentioning the other way to use text replacement, that I was thinking about... You could set like 2 or 3 letter repeats to convert to a single letter. So like `sss` → `ß`. 3 repeats  would probably be safe, but 2 is likely going to be triggered accidentally.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should be able to do that under System Preferences/Keyboard and look for customizations.  There is a representation of what each modifier key does wrt the rest of the keys.
In any case, search in this site for "umlaut" and see if that helps.

Yeh, there it is...
[Mountain Lion - Umlauts with english keyboard layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66450/mountain-lion-umlauts-with-english-keyboard-layout/66458#66458)

H

Comment: I can't find any customizations in the keyboard settings

Comment: There is no way to customize anything like this in MacOS other than via text replacements,